# Angular:How to print timezone in angular based on local browser time zone?

Tags: angular, date

I want to print the particular format MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM local browser time zone (ex: 09/21/2023 00:09 AM IST) through date pipe.

I tried this -
this.currentDate = new Date();
this.formattedDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.currentDate, 'MM/dd/YYYY HH:MM a');
through this code I can get upto here - 09/21/2023 00:09 AM. But not able to print IST or some other based on local browser time at the end.  Is there any way to add this time zone at the end of date to achieve like this 09/21/2023 00:09 AM IST?

Answer (score 0):

You must set the format in datePipe transform like following:

```
this.datePipe.transform(this.currentDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a zzzz');
```

Comment: @parimala-tamanampudi Was this post helpful to you? If yes, please mark as solved